# SQL - Get a student's all choices

Tags: sql

The background is that students can select different classes, set weight and choose a teacher (the choice is A, B, C, D) for the class, one class has four teachers.

Tables are like below

```
class:
id          integer
name        string
description string
```

```
student:
id   integer
name string
```

```
student_choice:
id         integer
class_id   integer
student_id integer
weight     decimal
choice     string
```

```
teacher:
id           integer
class_id     integer
choice       string
teacher_desc string
```

What I am trying to do is getting a student's all choices by his/her id, result looks like this

| class_id | class_name | weight | choice | teacher_desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Math | 0.2 | A | Alice |
| 3 | Music | 0.5 | B | Bob |
| 4 | Physical | 0.3 | A | Alan |

currently I just use student_choice table to find all classes that the student chooses, and
find the teacher correspond to student's choice

```
student.id --> student_choice --> class.id
class.id + student_choice.choice --> teacher
```

I don't know if it is possiable to implement this with just one SQL query, so I just use multiple queries and process them in my application.

Can anyone tell me what I should do to achieve my purpose with only one SQL query, or just keep the current situation because process them in my application instead of in database may be more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something, but it seems like a simple join between all tables can achieve that.

Something like that:

```
select sc.class_id, c.name, sc.weight, sc.choice, t.teacher_desc 
from student_choice sc, class c, teacher t
where sc.class_id = c.id
and sc.class_id = t.class_id and sc.choice = t.choice
and sc.student_id = {YOUR_STUDENT_ID}
```

Or if you prefer `inner join` syntax:

```
select sc.class_id, c.name, sc.weight, sc.choice, t.teacher_desc
from student_choice sc
inner join class c on sc.class_id = c.id
inner join teacher t on sc.class_id = t.class_id and sc.choice = t.choice
where sc.student_id = {YOUR_STUDENT_ID}
```